# MySQL create table containing values from a column in another table

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

Lets say I have a table `tilistings` with a dozen columns, and about 2,000 rows there is one column `cityname` that has probably 50 different values in it. What I want to do, is search through the `tilistings` and create another table that just contains the 50 different values from `cityname` without duplicating any names....basically if `cityname` had the values `a,b,a,c,b,b,d,a,a,d,d,c` I would only want the new table to contain `a,b,c`. Is there a pre-built MySQL function to do so? Otherwise, just point me in the right direction to do this with PHP. I can create the table, just looking to populate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the unique city names by performing the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cityname FROM tilistings
```

Then loop through those and INSERT them into your new table with PHP or [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html).

Answer (score 2):

Or do it all in SQL, if you already have created a table named `cities` with a single column `cityname`:

```
INSERT INTO `cities` (`cityname`)
SELECT DISTINCT `cityname` FROM `tilistings`;
```

Or crate the table from the `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE `cities`
SELECT DISTINCT `cityname` FROM `tilistings`;
```